# John 1:20 Why the triple emphasis on the confession?

Tags: john, john-the-baptist

> **John 1:20** He confessed, and did not deny, but confessed, “I am not the Christ.”

Why is it that it is so stressed here that John confessed,and did not deny, but confessed?

What is the motivation for this repetitive phrasing by the narrator of John's confession?

Comment: This just looks like common Hebrew prolix.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this is common to John's style of writing.  Also, repetition was common for emphasis in John's first language, Hebrew/Aramaic.

> § 6. Johannine repetition through negation

> [2598] This is very frequent both in narrative and in words of Christ. In 1:20 “and confessed and denied not and (A.V. but) confessed,” the negative (οὐ) is followed by “and” (instead of “but (ἀλλά),” which is almost invariably used). Very frequently the negation means “not of man,” or “not of this or that lower kind,” or “not evil”; and the affirmation means “but of God,” or “but of a higher kind” or “but good,” e.g. 1:13 “not … nor yet from the will of man, but from God,” 3:16 “should not perish but should have life eternal,” 3:17 “for God sent not his Son … that he should judge the world but that the world through him should be saved,” 5:24 “Cometh not into judgment, but hath passed from death into life,” 5:30 “I seek not mine own will, but the will of him that sent me.”
> ...

> [2600] There is no special ambiguity arising out of these constructions or out of John’s general use of the negative But it is worth noting that οὐ occurs in his Gospel almost as often as in Mark and Luke taken together. And we may often perceive how the negation leads the reader towards an affirmation in a very suggestive and stimulating way, as when our Lord says, “I have not come from myself,” “I am not alone,” “I speak not from myself,” “I seek not mine own glory,” and “I will not leave you orphans,” preparing the way for some positive doctrine. The negative, however, is not often thus used in communicating the highest kind of truth. After starting that the Baptist came to bear witness about the light, the evangelist proceeds, “He was not the light”; and his description of the “witness” is as follows: “And this is the witness … And he confessed and denied not and confessed, ‘I am not the Christ’ ”—the two subsequent answers being also negative (“I am not” “No”). Then, and not till then, follows the positive testimony. The writer perhaps feels that divine teaching is often a “dark saying” misunderstood for a time, and that the interpreter must explain by negatives, “not this but that.” At all events the last saying of Jesus recorded in this Gospel affords an instance of a “not … but” correcting a misunderstanding; “But Jesus said not unto him that he was not to die, but.…”
> --
> Abbott, E. A. (1906). *Johannine Grammar* (p. 445-446). Adam and Charles Black.

Other authors state this is less detail, but the detail above better answers your question.

> And he confessed (και ὡμολογησεν [kai hōmologēsen]). The continued paratactic use of και [kai] (and) and the first aorist active indicative of ὁμολογεω [homologeō], old verb from ὁμολογος [homologos] (ὁμον, λεγω [homon, legō], to say the same thing), to confess, in the Synoptics (Matt. 10:32) as here. And denied not (και οὐκ ἠρνησατο [kai ouk ērnēsato]). Negative statement of same thing in Johannine fashion, first aorist middle indicative of ἀρνεομαι [arneomai], another Synoptic and Pauline word (Matt. 10:33; 2 Tim. 2:12). He did not contradict or refuse to say who he was. And he confessed (και ὡμολογησεν [kai hōmologēsen]). Thoroughly Johannine again in the paratactic repetition.
> --
> Robertson, A. T. (1933). *Word Pictures in the New Testament* (Jn 1:20). Broadman Press.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for these citations, however the examples provided seemed to be of a double emphasis.   I don't think I would haved noticed if John had said that "he confessed and did not deny", or alternatively that "he did not deny, but confessed." It's the triple emphasis that performs a pattern break for me and makes me think there is something more significant here that I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some other peculiarities in the verse of John 1:20.

1. John’s reply does not in fact directly answer the question that was posed to him, which was “Who are you?”
2. The “I” in his reply is emphatic as in “*I* am not the Christ” (see
   Vincent’s Word Studies [here](https://biblehub.com/commentaries/john/1-20.htm))
3. Though John’s answer appears to be a denial (“I am not the Christ”),
   the text emphasizes that it is not a denial, but a confession.

Together with the OP’s observation, these idiosyncrasies suggest that there is something deeper hidden in John’s reply. Taking the triple emphasis as an interpretative cue, rather than just a method of emphasis, it occurred to me that there are three confessions hidden in John’s answer. John’s reply in Jn 1:20 serves as a foundation for all three, but the subsequent verses in the text fill out the details of each.

1/ The first is a confession about who John is. “I am not the Christ” is not a denial but a revelation about his own identity. “I am not the Christ,” but Christ is integral to who I am.

> 22 Then they said to him, “Who are you? Tell us, so that we may give
> an answer to those who sent us. What do you say about yourself?” 23 He
> said, “I am the voice of one calling out in the wilderness, ‘Make the
> way of the Lord straight,’ as Isaiah the prophet said.”

2/ The second is a confession of Christ’s existence. “*I* am not the Christ,” but there is one who exists who is the Christ.

> 25 They asked him, and said to him, “Why then are you baptizing, if
> you are not the Christ, nor Elijah, nor the Prophet?” 26 John answered
> them, saying, “I baptize  in water, but among you stands One whom you
> do not know. 27 It is He who comes after me, of whom I am not worthy
> even to untie the strap of His sandal.”

3/ Last but not least is a confession about Christ’s identity. “I am not the Christ” because who Christ is, I am not nor can I be.

> 29 The next day he saw Jesus coming to him, and said, “Behold, the
> Lamb of God who takes away the sin of the world! 30 This is He in
> behalf of whom I said, ‘After me is coming a Man who has proved to be
> my superior, because He existed before me.’ 31 And I did not recognize
> Him, but so that He would be revealed to Israel, I came baptizing in
> water.” 32 And John testified, saying, “I have seen the Spirit
> descending as a dove out of heaven, and He remained upon Him. 33 And I
> did not recognize  Him, but He who sent me to baptize in water said to
> me, ‘He upon whom you see the Spirit descending and remaining upon
> Him, this is the One who baptizes in the Holy Spirit.’ 34 And I myself
> have seen, and have testified that this is the Son of God.”

Comment: +1 for taking the subject seriously and providing some food for thought. Need to meditate some more on this. Thank you.

Comment: Whatever the true meaning of the text may be, I believe your instincts are on point. There is something significant to be uncovered here.